# Share large file with all nodes in docker swarm

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

Currently, I am migrating to Docker Swarm and have begun to use docker configs to offload most of the configuration files but I have one file remaining that is several GBs that is used by my tileserver. Right now, I have a 1 master / 4 workers and I am looking for a way to share that file with all nodes in the swarm to prepare for a time when the tileserver goes down.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want highly available data then a solution that distributes data amongst nodes (or servers).

One approach would be deploying an object storage solution onto the swarm - something like minio gives you an s3 compatible REST api and when deployed with a minimum of 4 disks in erasure coding mode tolerates 1 disk down for writing and 2 disks down for reading (assuming you have a node per disk).

If re-jigging your app to work with object storage isnt in scope then investigate something like glusterfs which you will want to install on the metal, rather than on docker. glusterfs will give you a unified filesystem with decent HA on 3 nodes, you can add disks on the fly.

Obviously with minio its expected your app would use the s3 api to access its files. With glusterfs you would need to mount gfs volumes on host locations where containers than then mount volumes to gain access to that network storage.
unless you are willing to go wandering through the world of rex-ray and other community supported docker volume drivers that either havn't seen an update in years or are literally maintained by one guy for fun which can bring some first class support for glusterfs based docker volumes to your hopefully non production docker swarm.